# html canvas do not fill entire page on firefox mobile

Tags: html, firefox, canvas, mobile

I'm trying to use a canvas animation effect, it works well on firefox (desktop) but on mobile it fills like little space on top left corned of the page. On mobile chorome works well, updated my browser still not working, wonder if there is any trick making it work.

```
code
```

https://codepen.io/riazxrazor/pen/Gjomdp

here is the html file on separate server:

http://ntf.r-control.eu/canvas.html

Not posting code here, becouse it not display properly (goes out the code tag somehow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not able not to understand your doubt. But, you can try

```
canvas{
    height: 100vh;
    width: auto;
}
```

it will force your canvas to be the height and width of the viewport.